# Memory-management in iOS Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I have a little problem with memory management in my iOS App. I load an XML and set all Values in this XML to Spezific Objects. Now my problem is when i reload the XML every 15 - 20 reloads of this XML my app Crash on Parsing here is a sample of my parser.

EDIT: Here ist the ERROR when NSZombie is Enabled if NSZombie is disabled I didn't get an ERROR message.
 -[CFNumber retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

thanks for help.

EDIT:

the beginning of my Code:

```
 - (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        TheObjects *theObjects = [[TheObjects alloc] init];

        [self parse];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) reload{
    reload = YES;
    TheObjects *theTmpObjects = [[TheObjects alloc] init];
     [self parse];
}
- (void)parse{

for (id xmlOBject in xmlObjects){
    MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    object.number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    object.number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    object.number3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

    if (reload)
        [theTmpObjects.objects addObject:object];
    else 
        [theObjects.objects addObject:object];

    [object release];
}
//later in my code

TheObjects *localTheTmpObjects = nil;
if (reload){
    localTheTmpObjects = theObjects;
    theObjects = theTmpObjects;
}

if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finished:)]){
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(finished:) withObject:theObjects];
}

if(reload)
    [localTheTmpObjects release];
```

}

Comment: what's the error displayed and what the line? do u know?

Comment: here ist the error when i enabled NSZombie  -[CFNumber retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: Just use ARC, It will fix all of your problems!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I agree, I only had a few leaks since I started using ARC, and they were very easy to fix. One should always be careful about retain cycles though, as ARC will not prevent them

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Or is it an attempt to recreate the actual code?  It does not make sense at all.   For example, inside the if {} in your init you have  `TheObjects *theObjects = [[TheObjects alloc] init];`.   That variable "theObjects" will only be around until the close-}.  Then the object will leak.  But later you seem to be referencing "theObjects".  If this is your real code, it makes no sense and you have bigger problems than a message to a deallocated instance.  Put your real code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
remove the line [localTheTmpObjects release]

you don't own the object

at the end, call the  `[localTheTmpObjects autorelease];`
this is because if you release array, all its objects are released and hence may cause crash, when your array may in use

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            TheObjects *obbjects = [[TheObjects alloc] init];
    theObjects = objects;
[objects releas];
            [self parse];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void) reload{
        reload = YES;
TheObjects *obbjects = [[TheObjects alloc] init];
    thetmpObjects = objects;
[objects releas];         [self parse];
    }
    - (void)parse{

    for (id xmlOBject in xmlObjects){
        MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        object.number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        object.number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
        object.number3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

        if (reload)
            [theTmpObjects.objects addObject:object];
        else 
            [theObjects.objects addObject:object];

        [object release];
    }
    //later in my code

    TheObjects *localTheTmpObjects = nil;
    if (reload){
        localTheTmpObjects = theObjects;
        theObjects = theTmpObjects;
    }

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finished:)]){
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(finished:) withObject:theObjects];
    }


    }
```

Comment: yeah this is due to relaesed object. if you have nsmutable array, then use
[NSMutablArray arra]; and remove the release calls, this will return u a retained object or mutable array

Comment: yeah i got it, you have not allocated localtempObjects and releasing it, see edited answer

Comment: I have edit my code samply i hope you would now understand my code